# Subscribe multiple observables within an observable response array angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and rxjs world, i would like to achieve the below,
[Cards[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnpq0.png)

I have two angular services that returns an observable response.

When i subscribe first service, it returns an array of 3 site urls, consider res[3]=[xyz.com, abc.com, pqr.com]

Next, i need to query the second service by passing the above received urls to fetch details from each site.

finally i should have the response received from my first service and associated details that i got from the second service for each of the sites.

like

**xyz.com** ->>
visited user,
visited user name,
number of hits,
so on....

**abc.com** ->>
visited user,
visited user name,
number of hits,
so on....

**pqr.com** ->>
visited user,
visited user name,
number of hits,
so on....

any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Service 1:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class Services1 {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

   getSitesList(): Observable<any>{
       return this.http.get('https://url')
         .map(data => {
            console.log(data);
         });
    }
}
```

**Service 2:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class Services2 {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

   getSitesDetailsList(sites): Observable<any>{
       const observableBatch = [];
       sites.forEach((siteName)=> {
           if (siteName) {
              observableBatch.push(this.getSitesDetails(siteName));
           }
       });
       return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);

    }

   getSitesDetails(name): Observable<any>{
       return this.http.get('url/name')
         .map(data => {
            console.log(data);
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: It helped me in a way to achieve my requirement. thanks